# Why do javascript string split method support an array as separator?

Tags: javascript, string, split

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the split method separator is treated as a String or a RegExp. But 'asd'.split(['s']) correctly returns ['a', 'd'].

Comment: A lot of JS functions will try to coerce their argument(s) to the required type(s). `['s'].toString()` gives `'s'`.

Comment: MDN says the separator is *treated* as a string. So this probably works because `String(['s']) === 's'`.

Comment: *"If separator is a RegExp object (its [[Class]] is "RegExp"), let R = separator; otherwise let R = ToString(separator)."*

Comment: the coercion rules as said by nnnnnn in fact `"111a,s222".split(['a','s'])` splits since `""+['a','s'] == 'a,s'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.split) for `split` includes the following step:

> 12. Let R be ToString(*separator*).

So the array is coerced to a string, and the string representation of `['s']` is `s`.

It's worth noting that if you pass a regex to `split`, it doesn't get this far, as the regex object has an internal `@@split` method, which is used in step 3:

> 3. If separator is neither undefined nor null, then
>
>    a. Let splitter be GetMethod(separator, @@split).
>
>    b. ReturnIfAbrupt(splitter).
>
>    c. If splitter is not undefined , then
>
>    i. Return Call(splitter, separator, «‍O, limit»).

Comment: Yes, you're right, I just checked it with an example `console.log('as,df'.split(['s', 'd']) );`